# Performance attribution of indices to their sector weights

Tags: time-series, statistics, asset-returns

Is it possible to attribute performance of indices (monthly returns and risk measures - Sharpe ratio, etc.) to their sector weights (if I know them)?

Example: I know the monthly performance of various indices and I know the proportions they invest in each sector each month (e.g. health care 10%, utilities 5%, etc. in January - same for other months). Is it possible to find how the particular sectors attribute to the performance of indices from these inputs?

Comment: As concerns return, could it be that you are looking for the asset allocation/stock selection performance attribution according to Brinson/Fachler as described here: https://breakingdownfinance.com/finance-topics/modern-portfolio-theory/brinson-model/ if I have time later, I would expand this to an answer.

Comment: If you know the index returns and sector weights, can you not calculate the sector returns? Alternatively, you can often find indices for sectors e.g. MSCI or S&P given a parent index.

Answer (score 1):

You can attribute all of those to sectors, but unfortunately only if you know the sector returns